# vector and c array in context of vecLib

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, accelerate-framework

I wish to make use of vecLib inside Accelerate Framework. I noticed that the data types are typedefed to 'vector'. How do I initialise it from a c-array during runtime?

EDIT: With help from Zaph, my question reduces to this.

Comment: @trojanfoe I don't think it is a c++ vector...

Comment: @Zaph How do I initialise it from a c-array after declaration? I'm not able to do stuff like `myVector[i] = theArray[i];` where `myVector` is `vUInt32` and `theArray` is array of 4 unsigned 32-bit int while I can do stuff like `myVector = {14,32,55,42}`

Comment: Basically, I wish to initialise them during runtime.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45121/discussion-between-roshan-and-zaph)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a better way if you wade through all the headers but this seems to work:

```
    vUInt32 vUI;
    uint32_t *vp = (uint32_t *)&vUI;
    vp[0] = 0;
    vp[1] = 1;
    vp[2] = 2;
    vp[3] = 3;
```

Example addition:

```
uint32_t *vp;
vUInt32 vUI1;
vp = (uint32_t *)&vUI1;
vp[0] = 0;
vp[1] = 1;
vp[2] = 2;
vp[3] = 3;
NSLog(@"vUI1: %d, %d, %d, %d", vp[0], vp[1], vp[2], vp[3]);

vUInt32 vUI2;
vp = (uint32_t *)&vUI2;
vp[0] = 4;
vp[1] = 5;
vp[2] = 6;
vp[3] = 7;
NSLog(@"vUI2: %d, %d, %d, %d", vp[0], vp[1], vp[2], vp[3]);

vUInt32 vUI3 = vU64AddS(vUI1, vUI2);
vp = (uint32_t*)&vUI3;
NSLog(@"vUI3: %d, %d, %d, %d", vp[0], vp[1], vp[2], vp[3]);
```

NSLog output:
vUI1: 0, 1, 2, 3
vUI2: 4, 5, 6, 7
vUI3: 4, 6, 8, 10

A helper function could be created like this:

```
void vUInt32With4Values(uint32_t value0, uint32_t value1, uint32_t value2, uint32_t value3, vUInt32 *vUI) {
    uint32_t *vp = (uint32_t *)vUI;
    vp[0] = value0;
    vp[1] = value1;
    vp[2] = value2;
    vp[3] = value3;
}

vUInt32 vUI1;
vUInt32With4Values(0, 1, 2, 3, &vUI1);
```